# Logcat in Android Studio is emitting more messages than it used to when my phone is attached--like 50/sec?

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat

When my phone is attached the Logcat in Android Studio emits more messages than it used to.  It never stops.  Like 50 logs a second.  Anybody know how I can tame this?

Also, I am using 'verbose', but I used to use that as well and it didn't have this many logs then either.

Here is an example of about 1 seconds worth of logging:

> 03-09 14:24:14.775 1576-3481/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 1 index
>   20 03-09 14:24:14.775 1576-3072/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 6
>   index 20 03-09 14:24:14.775 1576-1610/? D/AudioService:
>   getStreamVolume 5 index 20 03-09 14:24:14.785 1576-3480/?
>   D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 150 03-09 14:24:14.875
>   1576-2986/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener :
>   batteryPropertiesChanged! 03-09 14:24:14.875 1576-2986/?
>   D/BatteryService: level:31, scale:100, status:2, health:2,
>   present:true, voltage: 3846, temperature: 309, technology: Li-ion, AC
>   powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless
>   powered:false, icon:17303590, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0
>   03-09 14:24:14.885 1576-2986/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current
>   avg:364, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage
>   charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false,
>   current_now:420 03-09 14:24:14.885 1576-1576/? D/BatteryService:
>   Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. 03-09 14:24:14.885 1576-1576/?
>   I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged 03-09 14:24:14.885 1576-1576/?
>   D/MotionRecognitionService:   cableConnection= 1 03-09 14:24:14.885
>   1576-1576/? D/MotionRecognitionService: setPowerConnected | current
>   backoffstate  = 1024 , state =1024 03-09 14:24:14.885 1576-1576/?
>   D/MotionRecognitionService: skip setTransmitPower.  03-09 14:24:14.895
>   2489-2489/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast
>   android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED 03-09 14:24:14.895 2489-2489/?
>   I/PERF: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED 03-09
>   14:24:14.895 2489-2489/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
>   03-09 14:24:14.905 2954-2954/? D/BatteryMonitor: new battery level: 31
>   03-09 14:24:14.915 4068-4068/? V/HeadsetService: HeadsetService -
>   Received Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED 03-09 14:24:14.915 4068-4707/?
>   D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0 03-09
>   14:24:14.925 2489-2489/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED :
>   level:31 status:2 health:2 03-09 14:24:14.925 2489-2489/?
>   D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:31 status:2
>   health:2 03-09 14:24:14.925 2489-2489/? D/BatteryMeterView:
>   ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:31 status:2 health:2 03-09 14:24:15.095
>   1576-2557/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 20 03-09
>   14:24:15.105 1576-3771/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 4 index 20
>   03-09 14:24:15.105 1576-2919/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 0 index
>   20 03-09 14:24:15.115 1576-3070/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 1
>   index 20 03-09 14:24:15.115 1576-3071/? D/AudioService:
>   getStreamVolume 6 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.125 1576-3479/?
>   D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 5 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.125
>   1576-1608/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 150 03-09
>   14:24:15.435 1576-2986/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 20
>   03-09 14:24:15.445 1576-3773/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 4 index
>   20 03-09 14:24:15.455 1576-3778/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 0
>   index 20 03-09 14:24:15.465 1576-2557/? D/AudioService:
>   getStreamVolume 1 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.465 1576-3771/?
>   D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 6 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.475
>   1576-2919/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 5 index 20 03-09
>   14:24:15.485 1576-3070/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 150
>   03-09 14:24:15.505 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120
>   -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte level=4 03-09 14:24:15.505 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99
>   99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte
>   03-09 14:24:15.505 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=4 03-09 14:24:15.505
>   2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId =
>   com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mDataSignalIconId =
>   com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4
>   mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone four bars. 03-09 14:24:15.515
>   1576-2361/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: onSignalStrengthsChanged: Received
>   signal strength change, phone type is: 1 03-09 14:24:15.515
>   1576-4357/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: lastLteRSRP is -91currentLteRSRP is
>   -91 03-09 14:24:15.515 1576-4357/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: lastCdmaDb is -16currentCdmaDb is -16 03-09 14:24:15.515 1576-4357/?
>   V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: Radio oldest entry removed 03-09 14:24:15.515
>   1576-4357/? V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: New entry : (SignalStrength: 99 99
>   -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte : 0 ) 03-09 14:24:15.515 1576-4357/? V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: Radio entry
>   added 03-09 14:24:15.525 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 99 -120
>   -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte level=4 03-09 14:24:15.525 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99
>   99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte
>   03-09 14:24:15.525 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=4 03-09 14:24:15.525
>   2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId =
>   com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mDataSignalIconId =
>   com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4
>   mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone four bars. 03-09 14:24:15.535
>   1576-2361/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: onSignalStrengthsChanged: Received
>   signal strength change, phone type is: 1 03-09 14:24:15.535
>   1576-4357/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: lastLteRSRP is -91currentLteRSRP is
>   -91 03-09 14:24:15.535 1576-4357/? D/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: lastCdmaDb is -16currentCdmaDb is -16 03-09 14:24:15.535 1576-4357/?
>   V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: Radio oldest entry removed 03-09 14:24:15.535
>   1576-4357/? V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: New entry : (SignalStrength: 99 99
>   -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 25 -91 -13 84 -1 2147483647 0x4000 gsm|lte : 0 ) 03-09 14:24:15.535 1576-4357/? V/EPDG -- [SMARTWIFI]: Radio entry
>   added 03-09 14:24:15.625 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4
>   combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020713/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3
>   mobileLabel=AT&T wifiLabel="MindfireTech-2.4G" emergencyOnly=false
>   combinedLabel="MindfireTech-2.4G" mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0
>   mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020865/com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0201bb/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4
>   mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null)
>   mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020865/com.android.systemui:drawable/tw_stat_sys_5_level_signal_4_auto_rotate
>   mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0204ed/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_lte_att
>   mQSDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null)
>   mWifiIconId=0x7f020713/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3
>   mQSWifiIconId=0x7f0203cb/com.android.systemui:drawable/qs_tile_wifi_signal_3
>   mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f0206c4/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout
>   mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0206ed/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
>   03-09 14:24:15.635 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false) 03-09
>   14:24:15.635 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false) 03-09
>   14:24:15.635 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false) 03-09
>   14:24:15.635 2489-2489/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController:
>   refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false) 03-09
>   14:24:15.855 1576-1608/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 2 index 20
>   03-09 14:24:15.865 1576-3481/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 4 index
>   20 03-09 14:24:15.875 1576-1610/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 0
>   index 20 03-09 14:24:15.895 1576-3480/? D/AudioService:
>   getStreamVolume 1 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.895 1576-2472/?
>   D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 6 index 20 03-09 14:24:15.925
>   1576-2986/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 5 index 20 03-09
>   14:24:15.925 1576-3773/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and set the dropdown at the extreme right to "Show only selected application".

This way, only logs from the selected application will be logged.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Must have accidentally picked a different option.